# How do I get HTML to break on the word only?

Tags: html, css

Flowed text in HTML breaks either with or without a hyphen, or, if it's justified on the word.

How do I get said text to break on the word only *and* be ragged right?

*Example:*

The quick young fox jumps ov-

er the lazy hen.

*The desired output would be:*

The quick young fox jumps

over the lazy hen.

Comment: what do you mean break on the word only?

Comment: Break on words only and ragged right is the default behavior in HTML, unless you're doing something really strange.

Comment: Could you provide a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property that you are looking for is `word-break`

```
word-break: break-all;
```

Check at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/376qL5Lg/

---

To make the line continuing with no breaks the approach is:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7km0c6mb/

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite, the words in paragraph text would not break. No hyphens, no broken words.

Comment: You mean that you want the text to run off the page?  Never break?

Comment: In that case, instead of word-break, you can use white-space setting it to nowrap. New fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7km0c6mb/

Answer (score 0):

You could try the css property word-wrap.

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```